# There is a very large blank space on my website

Tags: html, whitespace

Here is the website of question: http://keyclub.paschalcs.org/about/

Does anyone know why there is that large block of white there opposed to on the home page...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the whitespace before the navigation

#### CSS Fix:

```css
#page #pagehold {
  width: 954px;
  margin-top: 120px;
}
```

#### Screenshot after fix:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work. #pageHold contains all on the homepage as well, therefore making the homepage be too far up. What I'm curious about is what's causing just this page to malfunction as so.

Comment: @JakeMartinez Can you post a screenshot and some annotation explaining what your actual issue is? I am kind of unclear. Which space are you talking about?

Comment: if you are getting problem only in home page. then create another class and override the new rule.

Answer (score 1):

you are giving more margin that's what the gap is coming:
replace this code:

```
#page #pageHold {
    margin-top: 120px;
    width: 954px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. #pageHold contains all on the homepage as well, therefore making the homepage be too far up. What I'm curious about is what's causing just this page to malfunction as so

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try this

```
#page #pageHold {
    margin-top: 120px;
    width: 954px;
}
```

you put some extra margin on the top of you page holder div

Comment: seems you fixed that in your code right?